# how to read images from my home directory and resize it

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to read the images and resize the image in my home directory file but didn't work please help how to read images and resize it.

```
    import cv2
    from PIL import Image
    img = cv2.resize(cv2.read('C://Users//NanduCn//jupter1//train-scene classification//train"', (28, 28)))


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-dab0f11a9e2d> in <module>()
      1 import cv2
      2 from PIL import Image
----> 3 img = cv2.resize(cv2.read('C://Users//NanduCn//jupter1//train-scene classification//train"', (28, 28)))

AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Please accept whichever answer answers your question best. (or else if none of them do, write your own answer and accept it).

Answer (score 1):

To read all images of particular extension, e.g. "*.png", one can use `cv::glob` function

```
void loadImages(const std::string& ext, const std::string& path, std::vector<cv::Mat>& imgs, const int& mode)
{
    std::vector<cv::String> strBuffer;
    cv::glob(cv::String{path} + cv::String{"/*."} + cv::String{ext}, strBuffer, false);

    for (auto& it : strBuffer)
    {
        imgs.push_back(cv::imread(it, mode));
    }
}

std::vector<cv::Mat> imgs;
loadImages("*.png", "/home/img", imgs, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
```

And then resize each image in buffer

```
for (auto& it : imgs)
{
    cv::resize(it, it, cv::Size{WIDTH, HEIGHT});
}
```

It should be easy to rewrite to python since almost all functions / data types have equivalents in python.

```
filenames = glob("/home/img/*.png").sort()
images = [cv2.imread(img) for img in filenames]

for img in images:
    cv2.resize(img, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
```

The code is divided to parts instead of one-liner because it is more readable, at least for me.

Comment: import glob
from glob import *
ilenames = glob.glob("C://Users//NanduCn//jupter1//train-scene classification//train*.jpg").sort()
images = [cv2.imread(img) for img in filenames]

for img in images:
    cv2.resize(img, (28, 28))

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-2324d4aae693> in <module>()
      1 import glob
      2 from glob import *
----> 3 ilenames = glob.glob("C://Users//NanduCn//jupter1//train-scene classification//train*.jpg").sort()
      4 images = [cv2.imread(img) for img in filenames]
      5 

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'glob'

Comment: First, i can see a typo `ilenames` instead of `filenames`. Also see edited answer. You have already imported glob function so instead of `glob.glob` use just `glob`.

Comment: @martonmarsuri If it solved your question, please dont forget to mark the right answer. Or if you have further questions, go on.

Answer (score 0):

Using glob module:

```
dpath = "C:/your_path/"
fmt = "png"    
size = (28, 28)

imgs = [cv2.resize(cv2.imread(fpath), size) for fpath in glob.glob("{}/*.{}".format(dpath, fmt))]
```

Answer (score 0):

the error here is that you are giving a directory to cv2.imread but it only accepts image-path as input else it throws the error.

so we can do is parse all the files in a folder using os module and then read the images one by one and than resize and do other operations on them.

```
import os
import cv2
from PIL import Image
size = (28, 28)
imagesPath = "C://Users//NanduCn//jupter1//train-scene classification//train"

for imageName in os.listdir(imagesPath):

    imageFullPath = os.path.join(imagesPath,imageName)
    img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(imageFullPath), size)
    #do your processing here
```

also i here consider that you only have images in that folder. if you have other types of files or other folders inside it you can put a check before the os.path.join line.

Hope this helps.